# How to Export sharepoint 2010 SPGridView data to excel

Tags: excel, export, spgridview

How to Export sharepoint 2010 SPGridView data to excel. My data with tree strutured is avilable in spgridview.

Note: if any of the column value contains multiple value then i need to convert into new value for each item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon it should work similar as the asp.net Gridview export to excel.
See this :
http://www.fivenumber.com/export-spgridview-to-excel-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint-2007/
Its for 2007 but should be ok for 2010
also see
http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html
Hope this helps
Cheres

Comment: yeah i am using above code only but i need to expand collapse section in excel sheet. like excel grouping or sharepoint list grouping.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this post - http://www.fivenumber.com/export-spgridview-to-excel-spreadsheet-in-sharepoint-2007/